# Download a file and save to blob (without saving to file)

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm using xmlhttprequest to download files(binary data, e.g., PDF) and save to blob (in memory instead of disk). The number of bytes downloaded is not correct. Can you give me some suggestions?

```
var url = ... // target file's url
var file_content = null;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.send();

if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
    file_content =xmlhttp.response;   // file_content's length is not correct.
}

var blob = new Blob([file_content],{type: 'text/plain'} );
```

Comment: Is the server sending the entire file? If you access the same url directly do you get the full file?

Comment: The target file is a static file and can be opened in browser. I guess it's about xmlHttpRequest.responseType - but in async mode, this item cannot be set as arrarybuffer.